# How to copy data from DataTable to Excel fast?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have got the below code from google to copy the datatable to excel fast. The cell by cell technique is very very slow.

Code:-

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;


xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Index";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Cat";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "CatNumber";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "ID";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Type";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Description";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Sou";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "IID";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "Time";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "TimeW";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "User";


if (dt1.TableName == Convert.ToString(objType1.Name))
{
    object[,] arr = new object[dt1.Rows.Count, dt1.Columns.Count];

    for (int r = 0; r < dt1.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt1.Rows[r];
        for (int c = 0; c < dt1.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            arr[r, c] = dr[c];
        }
    }

    //Set Excel Range to Paste the Data
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range c1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range c2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1 + dt1.Rows.Count, dt1.Columns.Count];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);

    //Fill Array in Excel
    range.Value2 = arr;
```

Note: dt1 is the datatable I have with multiple columns of different datatype. I am saving file to extension abc.xls.

Now, the problem I think I am facing is that whenever the description is huge, it throws an exception HRESULT OX800A03EC while copying that particular description to range.value2.

Comment: Do you have to write this to a excel file? Could you output to a csv instead?

Comment: Yes excel file..I am fine to copy to csv file but I assume that might create more problem as description contains mmany special characters like ':;,() etc. If it won't create an issue, I am more than happy to export it there. I just need that data to be exported to excel format.

Comment: Plus one thing if i perform the same task cell by cell..then long description gets copied without any issue but it causes a huge delay in performance which shouldn't be!

Comment: Tried by changing extension feom xls to csv but still the same expection..:-(

Comment: What do you mean by `description is huge`? How many characters is that? Can you make a reproductible sample for us?

Comment: Fill in an array instead, and then copy the array directly in the spreadsheet.  This is the fastest way.